# How to install different versions of same library in Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get

I'm trying to build an application (Visual Studio Code) from source on Debian. While trying to follow building instructions, Node-JS refused to install.

```
# apt-get install nodejs-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nodejs-dev : Depends: libssl-dev (>= 1.0.0g) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libc-ares-dev (>= 1.7.5) but it is not going to be installed
```

I've tried to install unmet dependencied one-by-one to find the problem source:

```
# apt-get install libssl-dev
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.1t-1+deb8u2) but 1.0.2d-1 is to be installed
              Recommends: libssl-doc but it is not going to be installed
```

A-and...

```
# apt-get install libssl1.0.0
libssl1.0.0 is already the newest version (1.0.2d-1).
```

There.
As I see, I have to install `libssl1.0.0` (to install that NodeJS) while keeping `libssl1.0.2d-1` (to avoid breaking any existing dependencies). How can I do it? And, most importantly, won't installing two versions of the same library introduce any errors?

Comment: Just to rule it out, you *have* run `apt-get update` recently, haven't you?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: yes, twice.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, so... is there a solution? :(